# How to produce XYZ folders from the OpenStreetMap PBF file

Tags: qgis, gdal, openstreetmap

I downloaded the 72 GB OpenStreetMap PBF file (planet-230619.osm.pbf) at this link https://planet.osm-hr.org/pbf/ and I was trying to upload it to QGIS and use the Generate XYZ tiles (Directory). Unfortunately, the application crashes. How can I solve it?

Is it right to proceed in this way or should I aim for solutions such as GDAL?